# Bottom view in coordinator layout not visible until scrolled down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to display a view below `Recyclerview` in `Coordinatorlayout` on starting the action mode. But until I scroll down bottom view is not visible. If I remove the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`,
I get what I want but then the Recyclerview goes below the toolbar. Any suggestions on how I can make the view visible all the time with `Coordinatorlayout`.

Main layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/list" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

list layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


<LinearLayout                               
    android:id="@+id/bottomView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutDummy">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempt below changes, by using "layout_weight" property it should calculate the view height without pushing your below view outside the visible borders. (its calculate the avilable height in runtime).

(I assumed the view you want to display below the Recycler view is the linerlayout)

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">




<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"                                          
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutDummy">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

  <LinearLayout                               
    android:id="@+id/bottomView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. On scrolling only the bottom view becomes visible. Scrolling behavior of Coordinator layout is responsible for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution by adding bottom view directly as a child to coordinator layout and making it visible on starting action mode. But the disadvantage to this solution is that bottom view hides the last row of the `Recyclerview`. So I had to add an empty footer at the end of the `Recyclerview`. Better solutions are most welcome.

Main layout :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/main_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="false">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <include layout="@layout/list" />

 <!-- BOTTOM VIEW -->
    <LinearLayout                               
       android:id="@+id/bottomView"   
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

list layout :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutDummy">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
private static final int TYPE_FOOTER = 2;

 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionFooter(position)) {
        return TYPE_FOOTER;
    }
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isPositionFooter(int position) {
    return position == list.size();
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (list == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return list.size() + 1;
    }
}
```